# Is there any C++ library (for Linux) for repairing the non-manifold meshes and converting it to manifold geometry?

Tags: mesh, cgal, surface, geometry-surface, libigl

I have the segmentation results from one algorithm, however, the generated triangle surface is not manifold geometry. I am asking this question here if there is any C++ library that can be used for converting the non-manifold geometry to manifold surfaces?

PS, I have already cleaned the result by filling the holes, but it seems that there are still some non-smoothed parts and holes.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please share one of triangle surfaces that you cannot process? I believe [MeshLib](https://github.com/MeshInspector/MeshLib) can help you, but without a sample of the problem, it is hard to suggest some particular tool from there.

Answer (score 1):

> If there is any C++ library that can be used for converting the non-manifold geometry to manifold surfaces?

Yes, there is [**CGAL**](https://www.cgal.org/), the **C**omputational **G**eometry **A**lgorithms **L**ibrary.

In CGAL, a [*polygon mesh*](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/index.html#title1) is considered to have the topology of a 2-manifold.
And when the faces of a polygon mesh are given but the connectivity is unknown, this set of faces is called a [*polygon soup*](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/index.html#title38). That is to say, all the triangles of your surface will be treated separately.

To convert a non-manifold surface into manifold, you can *first* load your data into a *polygon soup*.
*Then* convert it into a *polygon mesh* using the function [`polygon_soup_to_polygon_mesh`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__repairing__grp.html#gae4bb69cfd25240e8f929239b02d8c7f8). The following [code snippet](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/Polygon_mesh_processing_2orient_polygon_soup_example_8cpp-example.html) from CGAL gives an example:

```cpp
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel          K;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<K, CGAL::Polyhedron_items_with_id_3>      Polyhedron;

std::ifstream input(filename);
std::vector<K::Point_3> points;
std::vector<std::vector<std::size_t> > polygons;
if(!input || !CGAL::read_OFF(input, points, polygons) || points.empty())
{
  std::cerr << "Cannot open file " << std::endl;
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::orient_polygon_soup(points, polygons);
Polyhedron mesh;
CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::polygon_soup_to_polygon_mesh(points, polygons, mesh);
```

---

Or you can try to repair the surface mesh as depicted in [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/index.html#title46).